# Error after moving <mvc:annotation-driven/>: no declaration can be found for element 'mvc:annotation-driven'

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a dispatcher-servlet.xml and an applicationContext.xml.

I have been doing some refactoring, and moved

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.xxx"/>
```

from dispatcher-servlet.xml to applicationContext.xml.

I now get this error:

```
2012-01-26 10:34:36.434:WARN::Nested in org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 11 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'context:component-scan'.:
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'context:component-scan'.
```

My applicationContext.xml looks like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:ehcache="http://ehcache-spring-annotations.googlecode.com/svn/schema/ehcache-spring"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://ehcache-spring-annotations.googlecode.com/svn/schema/ehcache-spring http://ehcache-spring-annotations.googlecode.com/svn/schema/ehcache-spring/ehcache-spring-1.2.xsd"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd"
        >

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.xxx"/>

    <bean id="templateErrorListener"
          class="com.stringtemplate.log.Slf4jStringTemplateErrorListener"/>

    <bean id="ehCacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean"
          p:config-location="/WEB-INF/ehcache.xml"/>

    <ehcache:annotation-driven cache-manager="ehCacheManager"/>

</beans>
```

and my dispatcher-servlet.xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
        <property name="order" value="1"/>
        <property name="mediaTypes">
            <map>
                <entry key="json" value="application/json"/>
            </map>
        </property>
        <property name="defaultViews">
            <list>
                <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView"/>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="ignoreAcceptHeader" value="true"/>
    </bean>

    <bean class="com.stringtemplate.StringTemplateViewResolver">
        <property name="templateErrorListener" ref="templateErrorListener"/>
        <property name="templateRoot" value="/WEB-INF/templates/"/>
        <property name="order" value="2"/>
    </bean>
    <!-- Resolves view names to protected .jsp resources within the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="order" value="3"/>
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
        <property name="messageConverters">
            <list>
                <ref bean="formHttpMessageConverter"/>
                <ref bean="stringHttpMessageConverter"/>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="formHttpMessageConverter "
          class="org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter "/>
    <bean id="stringHttpMessageConverter "
          class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter "/>

    <bean id="restTemplate" class="org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate"/>

    <bean id="applicationProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:${systemTargetEnv}/app.properties</value>
                <value>classpath:/build.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="systemPropertiesModeName">
            <value>SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I have been doing some refactoring, and moved `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` from `dispatcher-servlet.xml` to `applicationContext.xml`.

You don't want to do that. `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` is there to enable annotation-style MVC controllers, and those controllers must reside in `dispatcher-servlet.xml`. Putting `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` in `applicationContext.xml` is pointless, it will have no meaningful effect.

I should probably answer the question, though, amnd the answer is that while you've declared the `mvc` namespace, you did not tell Spring where to find the schema for it.  Add

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
```

to the `schemaLocation` attribute in `applicationContext.xml`

Comment: Thanks for your answer - I've moved that, but now I get the error on the context.  I think I have updated the schema.  I've amended the question to reflect this.  I thought the component-scan should go in app context?!

Comment: Thanks, I updated my context schema location, and now we're all working again.  Thanks!!